# How to get value of a dropdown in word

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I am using this

```
doc.FormFields("ddShippingtype").DropDown.value
```

But it's returning position of the selected value in the dropdown list how can I get the actual text that's been selected?

Currently it's just returning Integers like 1, 2, ... based on the what the position is of the selected value in the dropdown list.

I just can't get this to work any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rohan,
I believe this is what you're after:

```
doc.FormFields("ddShippingtype").Result
```

Hope this helps. If not, let me know.